# Pyspark Clarification required on Label Indexing in LogisticRegression

Tags: python, apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml, multiclass-classification

I am using pyspark 2.4.5.

I have spark dataframe with x number of features . I have my target label with 3 classes "High","Medium","Low".

I am doing label indexing before building  logistic regression model .

So far good .

What is the problem I have ?
Whenever I want to do model building I am doing label indexing . Every time I do label indexing pyspark shuffles the indexes . For the first run when target label value for  High if it is given 1 next time it assigns 0 .

What help I need ?
I need a solution so that always my target label values has to be assigned as for High:2. For Medium:1 and for Low:2

Solution I thought of
Without using label indexing can I create a new column and map the target values as per my need .Can we do it like this ?.When I predict scores can I consider the same mapping as I have done during training

If label indexing is the only way then how any reference links will be helpful . I always want to map the  label indexing as High:2. For Medium:1 and for Low:2

Any solutions or reference links will be very very helpful

Comment: What estimator are you using for labelIndexing? Is it `StringIndexer`?

Comment: Yes using StringIndexer

Comment: StringIndexer assigns most frequent Labels is assigned `0` with default `frequencyDesc`, if your dataset is constant, then this exchange of indexing shouldn't happen. Are you using any non-deterministic operation(like `df.randomSplit`) before `StringIndexer`?

Answer (score 1):

The string indexer assigns value based on the frequency. May be in each run during the random split, your samples are differing in target labels. The best way is to use IndexToString() during predicting.

So, you save your string indexer model at the training and use it during preidction. Irrespective of the assigned integer, you will get back your high,low,medium as the prediction.

```
ind_str = IndexToString(inputCol='prediction',outputCol='pred_label',labels=pipeline_label.stages[0].labels)
```

In the above cases I had stored my pipeline during the training. So during predicting I load the pipeline back and use the stage 0 of the pipeline which was StringIndexer.

The same can be done also without the pipeline with just the model

Comment: Hi Raghu, I liked this approach during predicting should I give it in this way              

            pipe = Pipeline(stages = string_indexes + onehot_indexes + [assembler, label_indexes, rf])

            pipe = Pipeline(stages = onehot_indexes + [assembler, label_indexes, rf])
            mod = pipe.fit(data_frame)                                                                      
            mod.save().

           For loading I am using like below 
           model_rf=PipelineModel.load("<Your Model Path >")

          Now where should I use your code

Comment: after loading the pipeline, you go ahead and do the prediciton . `df_predict = model.rf.transform(data)`. Now df_predict should contain a column 'prediction' or whichever value you gave as 'predictionCol' while defining your rf.  With this predicted column you apply the indextostring. `ind_str = IndexToString(inputCol='prediction',outputCol='pred_label',labels=pipeline_label.stages[0].labels) df_predict_labels = ind_str.transform(df_predict)` Now df_predict_labels will contain a column 'pred_label' that will have your target classes as string

Comment: Thanks Raghu,I will try, If any issues can I keep this comment section until tomorrow pls. I have one more doubt, Today I have trained my model , predicted task is complete. Tomo I am doing the same exercise then the indexes will be shuffled again right . How do we handle this . For one complete run from training till prediction should be ok . Tomo if I retrain then how will I maintain yesterday's indexes ?

Comment: Yes sure. If it retrains then the label will be shuffled again. But often training is done occasionally. Once we have a model , then we will only be predicting, so the labels are valid. When you have to retrain, the labels are shuffled, but since you will load the new model during predicting, the shuffled labels are already taken care. so no code changes is needed. If it helps, please accept and upvote, so this question is not in my query again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create column which is kind of rule based -

```scala
df.withColumn("label_index", expr("case when(label='High') then 2 when(label='Medium') then 1 else 0 end"))
```

Comment: I have this solution my point is, can I use it like this and feed this label_index as y variable ?. Or should I perform only via StringIndexer approach .

Comment: You can use that. But I'm not sure how it will affect your algo accuracy. I would suggest _compare this approach with `StringIndexer` and use the one having better accuracy_

Comment: predictions were getting impacted when I compared both the results I thot going with StringIndexer approach would be good

Comment: yes it is always recommended approach. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/ml-features.html#indextostring

Comment: Today I have trained my model , predicted task is complete. Tomorrow I am doing the same exercise then the indexes will be shuffled again right . How do we handle this . For one complete run from training till prediction should be ok . Tomo if I retrain then how will I maintain yesterday's indexes ?

Comment: Always take labels from the stored stringIndexer model.